# Is there a scenario where pressing Ctrl + G and selecting blanks would not highlight empty cells?

Tags: excel, pdf, copy-paste, vba

I copied a bunch of tables from a PDF file to Excel. these tables contain empty cells. I need to write a code that'll be able to recognize and count the number of empty cells in each column of each table (I am saving one table per sheet).
I posted the following question [IsNumeric function returning true for an empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225497/isnumeric-function-returning-true-for-an-empty-cell) and thought I had the answer by calculating the length of the trimmed value of each cell, but it turns out that doesn't solve it. The length function returns a value of 5 for those empty cells. and a value of 5 for many other cells that have values.

When I click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and select blanks those empty cells are not highlighted. Only cells in columns that are entirely empty are highlighted.

Looks like I had a problem referencing my sheets. The command `isnumber` returns false, so that sort of solves my problem. but using `len(clean())` still returns a number bigger than zero. For now I can make do with the `isnumber` function. but I'd be interested to know what sort of value is stored in these cells.

Comment: can you upload one spreadsheet of your workbook? If the number returned from `Len(cell)` equals 5 that means there definitely are 5 characters in that cell. If they are not visible the font color may be set to white. Based on your other question I can't think of any other relevant alternative. You can add a breakpoint while iterating over cells in debug-mode and check the value of each cell by using `cell.value`,`cell.value2`,`cell.text`

Comment: when I click on a cell the function bar is empty. and when I debug to check cell value "MsgBox cell.value" it's also empty.

Comment: `Clean` only removes characters with ascii code < 32.  Other non-printing characters exist, eg non-break space (code 160).  Clean on its own will not remove these.

Comment: I see, that makes since, but still how do I identify those empty spaces? the function code(cell#) returns 32 for both the empty and non empty cells

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is that the cells actually contain non-printable characters such as carriage returns.

You can easily check this by using the following formula: `=LEN(CLEAN(A1))` which should return a different value compared to just `=LEN(A1)`